# Unable to access JSON data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing the following from my Django back-end to my front-end in order to dynamically build a form :

```
{
    "access_key": "93ec6137de00eacee6f8",
    "profile_id": "7851E15D64",
    "transaction_uuid": "c878c7e6db5657526",
}
```

Within the browser console, if I pass :

```
MyJSON = {
    "access_key": "93ec6137de00eacee6f8",
    "profile_id": "7851E15D64",
    "transaction_uuid": "c878c7e6db5657526",
    }
```

Then I can access each value properly, for example, MyJSON.access_key returns 93ec6137de00eacee6f8 perfectly within the console.

However, from my Javascript, I am unable to access any of those values as i get an "undefined".

```
var obj = JSON.parse(MyJSON)
console.log(obj) // returns the whole JSON String
console.log(typeof(obj)) // returns 'string'
alert(obj[0]) // returns "{", the very first character of the 'string'
alert(obj.access_key) // returns "undefined".
```

**- How can access each Key and Value from MyJSON from my javascript? (not JQuery)**

Note that I have reviewed many similar article but I must be missing the obvious ...

Hope you can assist !

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I have a list of Fields and a list of Values which i then merge into the below (pass the JSON Validator on https://jsonlint.com/):

```
   {'access_key': '93ec6137d70aada23400eacee6f8', 'profile_id': '7851E53E-96BB-4D4-BD5-0FE61CC15D64', 'transaction_uuid': '00939a90-db7b-41cb-af45-669ec5cc69e8', 'signed_field_names': 'bill_to_forename,bill_to_surname,bill_to_email,bill_to_phone,bill_to_address_line1,bill_to_address_city,bill_to_address_postal_code,bill_to_address_country,transaction_type,reference_number,payment_method,amount,currency,locale,card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date', 'unsigned_field_names': 'card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date', 'signed_date_time': '2021-05-23T16:20:17Z', 'bill_to_forename': 'John', 'bill_to_surname': 'Doe', 'bill_to_email': 'null@cfgfg.com', 'bill_to_phone': '07922889582', 'bill_to_address_line1': '123 Random Street', 'bill_to_address_city': 'London', 'bill_to_address_postal_code': 'RG1T3X', 'bill_to_address_country': 'GB', 'transaction_type': 'sale', 'reference_number': 'o6yejf', 'payment_method': 'card', 'amount': '100', 'currency': 'USD', 'locale': 'en', 'card_type': '001', 'card_number': '4456530000001096', 'card_expiry_date': '12-2026', 'signature': 'Un5gNYB5qZaRazzCDWqrdZuNkTRARIcfAt9aF2a1wbY='}
```

Back-end Code

```
    FieldList = ['access_key', 'profile_id', 'transaction_uuid', 'signed_field_names', 'unsigned_field_names', 'signed_date_time', 'bill_to_forename', 'bill_to_surname', 'bill_to_email', 'bill_to_phone', 'bill_to_address_line1', 'bill_to_address_city', 'bill_to_address_postal_code', 'bill_to_address_country', 'transaction_type', 'reference_number', 'payment_method', 'amount', 'currency', 'locale', 'card_type', 'card_number', 'card_expiry_date', 'signature']
    ValueList = ['93ec6137d0aada23400eacee6f8', '7851E53E-96BB-4DF4-BD55-0FE61CC15D64', 'c4fe96b0-063f-4b94-a6a5-2137bb796bd9', 'bill_to_forename,bill_to_surname,bill_to_email,bill_to_phone,bill_to_address_line1,bill_to_address_city,bill_to_address_postal_code,bill_to_address_country,transaction_type,reference_number,payment_method,amount,currency,locale,card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date', 'card_type,card_number,card_expiry_date', '2021-05-23T16:27:24Z', 'John', 'Doe', 'null@cyrce.com', '07922889582', '123 Random Street', 'London', 'RG1T3X', 'GB', 'sale', 'xl42fn', 'card', '100', 'USD', 'en', '001', '4456530000001096', '12-2026', 'vvb73h0GUpzUrvoG9VDaMc3vQRV5GsL4QTATc7IrrPA=']
    
NewFormat = dict(zip(FieldList, ValueList))
MyJSON = json.dumps(NewFormat, indent=4)
return JsonResponse(MyJSON, safe=False)
```

Apologies for the large amount of data.

I am somehow forced to use "safe=False" in my Python back-end otherwise I end up with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Droplet/Droplet/Harness/sasop2.py", line 543, in signsasop
    return JsonResponse(FinalJSONObject)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 561, in __init__
    'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

Since I am passing safe=False, is that why my front-end does not get the MyJSON as... JSON?

Would this be the root cause of the issue?

Front-End Sample :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

            // Print received data from server
            console.log('%c Processed Data \n',
            'background: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 30px'
            ,xhr.response);

            // Dynamically create the ReconstructedForm

            RawProcessedData = xhr.response
            console.log(RawProcessedData)

            // Convert to JSON
            var obj = JSON.parse(RawProcessedData)
            console.log(obj)
            console.log(typeof(obj))
            alert(obj[0])
            alert(obj.access_key)
```

Comment: Is your `MyJSON` actually valid JSON?  Can you post it?  If it's not double-quotes and otherwise valid JSON but a string, it will just return that string.

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve]. The code you've provided will not give the results you say it will. `MyJSON` is an object and not JSON. You can't parse it as JSON. It isn't a string before or after you try to parse it.

Comment: @Quentin I have added my back-end and a sample of the front end code. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: You’re JSON-encoding twice, so you’d also need to parse it twice… Of course, better yet: remove the superfluous manual `json.dumps`.

Comment: `MyJSON` isn't JSON data. `JSON.parse(MyJSON)` doesn't make sense. It seems you're confusing JSON with JavaScript objects and Python dictionaries because they look similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue when i started developing on Django. If you need to pass dictionarys from django to javascripts, the best thing to do is just using **django rest framework**. It serialize ( in other words, it transform any data into a dictionary/json ) any given data from a model.
But if you want to make this without Django Rest, you should use **fetch** on javascript. This fetch ( also called as a "**Promise**") communicate with the backend ( in this case, Django ) and it GET or POST data from the frontend. I will give you an example.

Supose you have this on **views.py**:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

def getJSON(request):
    MyJSON = {
        "access_key": "93ec6137de00eacee6f8",
        "profile_id": "7851E15D64",
        "transaction_uuid": "c878c7e6db5657526",
    }

    return JsonResponse(MyJSON)
```

And the you can link that to the **urls.py** like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('get-json', views.getJSON, name="get-json")
]
```

Then you can GET that JSON by doing this on your **javascript**:

```js
function getDataJson(){
    let url = 'get-json'

    fetch(url,{
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> console.log(data))
}
```

This will console log your data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your quick input !

As per deceze's answer, I was essentially double parsing both in the back and front end for no reasons.

Removing the json.dumps from the backend allows the JSON object to be passed and managed in the front end without issue.